# multi level referal system with django and mptt

Tags: django, django-mptt

I'm trying to create a referal structure like this:

[image]

I'm trying to use https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/

Which is the best approach to structure the database?

In a future I will be able to do query like this:

```
UserA.filter_referal(level=1)
[<User B>, <User C>, <User D>]

UserA.filter_referal(level=2)
[<User Z>, <User F>, <User E>, <User H>]

UserA.filter_referal(level=3)
[<User G>, <User i>]
```

Futhermore, which is the best way to structure the Database and associate each user to reflect the structure that I want?

```
class User(MPTTModel, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    …
    …
    …

    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)
```

Let's say UserA invite User B...

What should I do?

```
UserB.parent = UserA ?
```

And if UserB invite UserZ?

```
UserZ.parent = UserB
```

and so on.. ?

Let me know if this is the best way and if you have ideas/improvements.

Many thanks.

Edit some test with bad results:

```
>>> User.objects.all()
[<User: a>, <User: b>, <User: c>, <User: d>, <User: f>, <User: g>]
>>> users = _
>>> users[1].parent = users[0] # user a
>>> users[1].save() # user b
>>> 
>>> users[2].parent = users[0] # user a
>>> users[2].save() # user c
>>> 
>>> users[3].parent = users[2] # user c
>>> users[3].save() # user d
>>> 
>>> users[4].parent = users[2] # user c
>>> users[4].save() # user f 
>>> 
>>> users[5].parent = users[4] # user f
>>> users[5].save() # user g
>>> 
>>> users[0].get_descendants().filter(level=1)
[<User: b>, <User: c>]
>>> users[0].get_descendants().filter(level=2)
[<User: d>, <User: f>]
>>> users[0].get_descendants().filter(level=3)
[<User: g>]

# Why?
>>> users[4].get_descendants().filter(level=1)
[]

# But ? 
>>> users[4].get_descendants()
[<User: g>]


# Also

>>> users[2].get_descendants().filter(level=1)
[]
>>> users[2].get_descendants().filter(level=0)
[]
>>> users[2].get_descendants().filter(level=2)
[<User: d>, <User: f>]

# I expect:
>>> users[2].get_descendants().filter(level=1)
[<User: d>, <User: f>]
```

Comment: Those referrals might grow exponentially doesn't sound mptt is the proper tool for your use case, you'll get ridiculous trees, why not simply use a many to many field? You'll probably need async calculations to keep track of deeper levels, they will eat resources if your user base grows

Comment: I'v started with many 2 many but relationship are simmetrical:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440400/django-many-to-many-duplicate-relation-issue/31440868#31440868


Btw, I need to track only three level. Another ideas could be use three models like this:

FirstLevelReferal (user, invited_by)
SecondLevelReferal (user, invited_by)
ThirdLevelReferal (user, invited_by)

Comment: It's not clear to me that you really require ordering inside each level. This means that mptt might be too heavy for your use case. Why not take a look at an adjacency list-based implementation such as the AL_Node of https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/? (disclaimer: I'm affiliated with django-mptt, if anything)